# SQL / stored proc for SELECT Distinct rows with max date <= provided date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Thanks in advance:  Consider the following Tables:

```
Table 1: matrix_data
Matrix_ID   Data_ID     DATE(Date)  Info(varchar)
1               1       3000            A
1               1       3500            B
1               2       3600            C
1               2       3700            D
2               1       3100            E
2               1       3400            F
2               2       3450            G   
2               2       3750            H
3               1       3000            I
3               1       3500            J
3               2       3620            K
3               2       3700            L
4               1       3100            M
4               1       3400            N
4               2       3450            O
4               2       3750            P

Table 2:  Result_Query
Result_ID           Matrix_ID
22                  1
22                  3
```

Given the following -

```
A Date (for example - 3640)
A Data_ID (For example - 2)
A Result_ID (For example - 22)
```

I need a query that will give me back one row for each Matrix_id that has a record corresponding with the Result_ID (22). 
That Row should contain the record with max DATE <= provided Date (3640) for the records that also match the provided Data_ID (2).

```
For the example provided, the result would be :

Matrix_ID   Data_ID     DATE    Info(varchar)
1               2       3600        C
3               2       3620        K
```

I cannot change the Tables.  This is a small example, but I might have 5000 Matrix IDs in the Result_ID, so id like to do this without doing a trip to the DB for every record.
A stored proc is an option, if i can do it with straight sql all the better. 
I am working with oracle. DATE is a date column not a number. Thanks again -

So Far - Im trying to simplify the issue and just do:

```
select *
    from ( select b.* , rank() over ( partition by data_id, matrix_id order by DATE desc ) rnk
    from matrix_data b )
where rnk = 1
```

I now need to fold in the rest of the constraints

Comment: See this SO search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+oracle

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for classifying the problem - So far I tried to simplify the issue by just getting a rank - but getting no records back.  Need to read on Rank() / Partition, this is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

A simple group by is enough for this.

```
SELECT d.matrix_id, d.data_id, MAX(d.the_date) FROM matrix_data d
INNER JOIN result_query q ON q.matrix_id = d.matrix_id
WHERE d.data_id = ?
AND q.result_id = ?
AND d.the_date <= ?
GROUP BY d.matrix_id, d.data_id;
```

To include `info` you need to query this query:

```
WITH q1 AS
    (SELECT d.matrix_id, d.data_id, MAX(d.the_date) AS maxdate FROM matrix_data d
    INNER JOIN result_query q ON q.matrix_id = d.matrix_id
    WHERE d.data_id = ?
    AND q.result_id = ?
    AND d.the_date <= ?
    GROUP BY d.matrix_id, d.data_id)
SELECT q1.*, d.info FROM matrix_data d
INNER JOIN q1 ON q1.matrix_id = d.matrix_id
AND q1.maxdate = d.the_date
AND q1.data_id = d.data_id;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting an error. DATE column in table 1 is a DATE data type - it doesn't seem to like the max(d.date). I am also looking at other options with the rank function - I didn't realize this is a well classified n-per-group problem.

Comment: That can't be the problem. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: The following: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"     
*Cause:    
*Action: -- I actually have a working example below but Id like to get the simple group by working as well - one question - why is d.info in the group by clause?

Comment: d.info shouldn't be in the group clause. I edited my answer and added a second solution if you want to include info in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly working solution so far:

Any way to optimize?

```
SELECT Matrix_ID, Data_ID, DATE, Info
FROM ( SELECT M.*, rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY matrix_id, data_id ORDER BY DATE DESC ) rnk FROM matrix_data M 
JOIN RESULT_QUERY Q ON M.MATRIX_ID = Q.MATRIX_ID 
WHERE Q.RESULT_ID = 22
AND M.DATE <= to_date('12/20/1909','mm/dd/yyyy') )
WHERE rnk = 1;
```